# Does this unit test cover all edge cases?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-mvc

I want to test a simple controller and I want to know if this unit test covers all cases:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Tags> getAllTags(@RequestParam(value = "query", required = false) String query,
        @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false) Integer limit,
        @RequestParam(value = "start", required = false) Integer start,
        @RequestParam(value = "approved", required = false) Boolean approved,
        @ActiveLanguage Language language,
        @ActiveUser User user) {
    if (limit == null) {
        limit = 10;
    }
    if (start == null) {
        start = 0;
    }
    if (approved == null) {
        approved = true;
    }
    if (query != null) {
        return tagService.findTagsByQuery(user, query, limit, start, language, approved);
    } else {
        return tagService.findTags(user, limit, start, language);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testGetAllTags_query_notnull() throws Exception {
    List<Tags> tagsList = createTagList();

    //Individual parameters
    String query = "test";
    Boolean approved = true;

    Mockito.when(this.tagServiceMock.findTagsByQuery(user, query, limit, start, language, approved)).thenReturn(tagsList);

    List<Tags> t = tagController.getAllTags(query, limit, start, approved, language, user);

    assertSame(tagsList, t);
    assertNotNull(t);
    assertNotNull(tagsList);

    verify(tagServiceMock, times(1)).findTagsByQuery(user, query, limit, start, language, approved);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(tagServiceMock);

}

@Test
public void testGetAllTags_query_null() throws Exception {
    List<Tags> tagsList = createTagList();

    //Individiual Parameters
    String query = null;
    Boolean approved = true;

    Mockito.when(this.tagServiceMock.findTags(user, limit, start, language)).thenReturn(tagsList);

    List<Tags> t = tagController.getAllTags(query, limit, start, approved, language, user);
    assertEquals(tagsList, t);
    assertNotNull(t);
    assertNotNull(tagsList);

    verify(tagServiceMock, times(1)).findTags(user, limit, start, language);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(tagServiceMock);

}
```

Is there anything left that is not covered by this unit test?

Comment: generally speaking for each `if` branch you should have a test case. just based off of that rudimentary rule, no

Comment: I would agree - but being honest the "limit" and "start" thing is kind of not well written anyway and i don't want to test that. Is it ok besides the "limit" and "start" case?

Comment: I don't think there is currently enough information to answer your question.   What do the find tags functions do?  What parameters are they expecting? Can they throw errors? Is your code responsible for handling them if they are thrown? ...

Comment: "anyway and i don't want to test that". If you don't want to test it, why do you ask us whether you've covered everything?

Comment: I'm asking more if the general approach is fine - so yes -> i should test limit and start. But as I said - is it ok besides that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see the
[`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)
annotation can have a `defaultValue` parameter - once that's used the
method becomes a bit simpler:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Tags> getAllTags(@RequestParam(value = "query", required = false) String query,
        @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false, defaultValue = "10") int limit,
        @RequestParam(value = "start", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int start,
        @RequestParam(value = "approved", required = false, defaultValue = "true") boolean approved,
        @ActiveLanguage Language language,
        @ActiveUser User user) {
    if (query != null) {
        return tagService.findTagsByQuery(user, query, limit, start, language, approved);
    } else {
        return tagService.findTags(user, limit, start, language);
    }
}
```

I'd also consider some edge cases for `query`, like the empty string or
a string with just whitespace for that matter.

Now for the unit tests, the naming could probably be improved, but I
also don't pay that much attention to it to be honest.

If the `tagsList` (or any other part like mocking methods etc.) is a
common thing in the tests consider moving it into the `setUp` method (or
equivalent) so it doesn't clutter up the test methods.

The `assertSame` is fine, you're basically just testing whether the
object is passed through directly, however the "not null" tests
afterwards are useless - `tagsList` shouldn't (can't) be `null`, so why
is it being verified here?

`times(1)` is default for Mockito, so leave it out.  Also the
`verifyNoMoreInteractions` is a bit discouraged in general since it
might make tests more brittle than they'd have to be, also since you're
not gaining much from it here I'd leave it out too.

IMO since this is at the outermost layer I'd rather have an integration
tests that actually checks the parameter parsing and validation too -
this particular test doesn't have that much value considering you're
just passing through values.